# Limited popup like once per month and user

Tags: javascript

Is there a module for Drupal that has the following options:

- show a popup once in a month/day/...  should be configurable
- save this information in a cookie or else
- the popup should display some text and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if

[splashify](https://drupal.org/project/splashify) module can help you here

> Display a splash page anywhere on your site by redirecting the user,
>   showing a lightbox, or displaying a popup. This module is designed to
>   be search engine friendly, mobile device friendly and offers multiple
>   configuration options.Instead of using cookies to determine when the
>   splash page shows up, we use jStorage.

[Popup Message](https://drupal.org/project/popup_message)

> Display popup message for users once per browser session.